# Java Optional.isPresent avoid ternary

Tags: java, option-type

How do I use Optional.ifPresent if the function call also returns Optional.

For eg.

```
Optional<Item> itemTen = itemList.stream()
                   .filter(item -> item.val == 10)
                   .findFirst();
Optional<Item> item100 = itemTen.ifPresent() ? Optional.of(new Item(itemTen.get().val * 10)) : Optional.empty()
```

Is there a way to avoid ternary operator here ?

Comment: Just use the if else statement instead of the ternary operator and as your explanation, you don't' need the else event!

Comment: @Sweeper Updated. I really want to know if it is possible to do avoiding ternary or if else. Something like Optiona.ofNullable.

Comment: @MohamadGhaithAlzin what happens if itemTen is empty and I don't have else statement then

Comment: @NathanHughes findFirst returns Optional which may be empty. How do I use a flatMap here ?

Comment: So (using the answer from the linked original question) `Optional<Item> item100 = itemTen.map(it -> new Item(it.val * 10));`.